# Is there a way to click on .js file in the CSHTML editor and have it open?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2022, in a foo.cshtml file, I reference a number of .js files.

[image]

I would like to be able to click or Ctrl+click on `neutrals.js` and have Visual Studio open the file (as opposed to me finding it manually).

Is this functionality possible in Visual Studio 2022?